# count up the rows in acf (repeater-field) and add html output for every row

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I want to output a list element (

) for each row of an ACF repeater field. As soon as a new row is created, a new list element shoul be created with the value of the counter (cout up).

here is the code. the list elements should cout up according to the number of rows:

HTML:

```
<ul>
                     <li data-id="1" class="active">1</li>
                        <li data-id="2">2</li>
                        <li data-id="3">3</li>
                        <li data-id="4">4</li>
                        <li data-id="5">5</li>
                        <li data-id="6">6</li>
                        <li data-id="7">7</li>
                        <li data-id="...">...</li>


                    </ul>
```

PHP (ACF):

```
  <?php
                $i = 1;
                if (have_rows('referenz-slide')) :
                    $counter = 0;
                    while (have_rows('referenz-slide')) : the_row();
                    $counter++;

                        // vars
                        $title = get_sub_field('title');
                        $link = get_sub_field('link');
                        $text = get_sub_field('text');

                        ?>

                        <?php $state = "";
                        if ($i == 1) {
                            $state = "active";
                        } else {
                            $state = "hidden";
                        } ?>

                        <div class="referenz-content <?php echo $state; ?>" id="ref-<?php echo $i; ?>" data-referenz="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                            <h4 class="referenz-headline"><?php echo $title; ?></h4>
                            <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
                            <a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>" target="_blank" title="Jetzt mehr erfahren" class="btn btn-referenz">Jetzt mehr erfahren</a>

                        </div>

                        <?php $i++;
                    endwhile; ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I would like to increment the list items and the value of the data id (html output) according to the number of ACF rows. Can someone help?

Comment: Is 'referenz-slide' the repeater you want to do this for?

Comment: yes, 'referenz-slide' is the repeater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you pretty much have it all there already

```
<ul>
<?php while (have_rows('referenz-slide')) : the_row();?>

    <li data-id="<?php echo $i;?>" class="<?php echo $state; ?>">
        <?php echo $i;?>
    </li>

<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, that almost works. But the first list element is empty and has no digit, any ideas?